# Rewriting app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/contollers/Catalog/ProductController.php

Tags: magento-1.9, module, adminhtml, overrides, controllers

I am trying to rewrite app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/contollers/Catalog/ProductController.php. In my config.xml I have the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Product_CustomProduct>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Product_CustomProduct>
    </modules>
    <admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Product_CustomProduct before="Mage_Adminhtml">Product_CustomProduct</Product_CustomProduct>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
</config>
```

and in app/code/local/Product/CustomProduct/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php I have:

```
<?php
include_once("Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php");

class Product_CustomProduct_Catalog_ProductController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController
{
    /**
     * Save product action
     */
    public function saveAction()
    {
        echo 123456;
        die;
    }
}
```

I want to change saveAction function of core controller. But after product save my file echo is not working. My module is displayu on admin and it is enable. I dont know why my code is not working.

My newAction also not changed dont understand what is wrong in my structure.I dont want to change core file of magento.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281543/magento-overload-adminhtml-productcontroller-s-saveaction-method-won-t-work it will definately help you

Comment: i already check this but not able to solve my problem.

Comment: How can i check that my module is correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

Put your controller file under an `Admintml` folder. Better to use a similar folder path of the class which you are going to override.

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Product_CustomProduct>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Product_CustomProduct>
    </modules>
    <admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Product_CustomProduct before="Mage_Adminhtml">Product_CustomProduct_Adminhtml</Product_CustomProduct>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
</config>
```

and in app/code/local/Product/CustomProduct/controllers/Adminhtml/Catalog/ProductController.php

```
<?php
include_once("Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php");

class Product_CustomProduct_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController
{
    /**
     * Save product action
     */
    public function saveAction()
    {
        echo 123456;
        die;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working for me.

Comment: please check the system.log and/or exception.log for the possible errors

Comment: Only Notice and Warnings are present and they are not related to new product module.

Comment: My newAction also not changed dont undersatnd what is wrong in my structure.

Comment: worked as charm